# Synchronize scrolling between three divs proportionally

Tags: javascript

I have three divs: divA, divB and divC. I need to synchronize the scrolling between them proportionally so that:

- if I scroll divA, divB and divC should be autoscrolled proportionally
- if I scroll divB, divA and divC should be autoscrolled proportionally
- the same with divC

The following code does that but the scrolling is very glitchy, I thought that implementing a flag (the `ignoreEvent` variable) would prevent scrolling conflicts and it does but only when there are two divs (divA and divB for instance), as soon as I add a third one the scrolling conflicts appear again.

```js
let ignoreEvent = false;

function getScrollPercentage(element) {
  const scrollPercentage = element.scrollTop / (element.scrollHeight - element.offsetHeight);
  return scrollPercentage;

divA.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  const ignore = ignoreEvent;
  ignoreEvent = false;
  if (!ignore) {
    ignoreEvent = true;
    const divA_scrolledPercentage = getScrollPercentage(divA);
    divB.scrollTop = divA_scrolledPercentage * (divB.scrollHeight - divB.offsetHeight);
    divC.scrollTop = divA_scrolledPercentage * (divC.scrollHeight - divC.offsetHeight);
  }  
});

divB.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  const ignore = ignoreEvent;
  ignoreEvent = false;
  if (!ignore) {
    ignoreEvent = true;
    const divB_scrolledPercentage = getScrollPercentage(divB);
    divA.scrollTop = divB_scrolledPercentage * (divA.scrollHeight - divA.offsetHeight);
    divC.scrollTop = divB_scrolledPercentage * (divC.scrollHeight - divC.offsetHeight);
  }  
});

divC.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  const ignore = ignoreEvent;
  ignoreEvent = false;
  if (!ignore) {
    ignoreEvent = true;
    const divC_scrolledPercentage = getScrollPercentage(divC);
    divA.scrollTop = divC_scrolledPercentage * (divA.scrollHeight - divA.offsetHeight);
    divB.scrollTop = divC_scrolledPercentage * (divB.scrollHeight - divB.offsetHeight);
  }  
});
```

Here it is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-violet-z3irms?file=/src/index.js)

PD: I want to achieve this only with vanilla js.

Comment: Scrolling of all three columns is smooth for me on Mac Book Pro, and Chrome browser.

Comment: You can try setting a separate `ignoreEvent` for each listener.  Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-leaf-stwg5d?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working example, modify only the js part of your work.

```js
let mainScroller = null;

function getScrollPercentage(element) {
  const scrollPercentage =
    element.scrollTop / (element.scrollHeight - element.offsetHeight);
  return scrollPercentage;
}

const divA = document.getElementById('a');
const divB = document.getElementById('b');
const divC = document.getElementById('c');
/** @type {HTMLDivElement[]} */
const scrollers = [divA, divB, divC];

scrollers.forEach((thisScroller) => {
  // cache another scrollers, prevent create another array when scrolling
  const anothers = scrollers.filter((scroller) => scroller !== thisScroller);

  thisScroller.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    // if mainScroller is already existing, do nothing
    if (mainScroller) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(`Main scroller: ${thisScroller.id}`);

    // mark this scroller as main scroller
    mainScroller = thisScroller;

    const scrolledPercentage = getScrollPercentage(thisScroller);

    // scrolling anothers
    anothers.forEach((scroller) => {
      const scrollTop =
        (scroller.scrollHeight - scroller.offsetHeight) * scrolledPercentage;

      scroller.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    });

    // clear main scroller
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      mainScroller = null;
    }, 0);
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

#a,
#b,
#c {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#a {
  background-color: red;
}
#b {
  background-color: blue;
}
#c {
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
}

.content + .content {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="a">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="b">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="c">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's definitively less glitchy than my implementation but it's still glitchy. Sometimes when scrolling either up or down the scroller will go up a little bit, which makes scrolling action not very fluid.